# Save maps fragment & show same state on app relaunch

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

Would like to do following things:

**Save maps state on application close & show same state on app re-launch(internet may not available on app relaunch) :**

Let say user entered two locations in edit text provided & hit show button.Map fragment will show both locations on map as markers. If user press save button state of map fragment will be saved & when user re-launch application after closing or killing it same state of map fragment will be displayed as it was before closing application. Is it possible to do so?

Is google provide any api to store maps by third party application? In google maps application it allow users to save maps but am not sure whether third party apps which display maps can store maps or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While its technically possible, you still have to provide the appropriate information to have it "near" the state you left it.

Check out the [Camera and View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views) section of the documentation, setting the `target`, `zoom` and `tilt` looks like the information you need to save and re-set when relaunching the app. I believe these are what you need to be able to have the same state on relaunch.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

This is located at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/ 
Demos and sample code

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply @adjuremods. I guess approach you suggested will not work if there is no internet connection. Let say internet connection is available & search for a place from current location  then maps will show area between current location & searched location. I want same area to be displayed on map irrespective of internet available or not.